# Adding Sorbet RBI files to gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sorbet

I'm investigating what it might take to add Sorbet RBI files to gems that I maintain, and I'm trying to figure out the proper process for this. I don't want to have Sorbet as a runtime dependency for the gems, though, so that means having all the type information in a separate RBI file.

My current queries around this are:

- Do I add my own `rbi` file at, say, `./sorbet/rbi/gemname.rbi`? And is that where Sorbet will look by default if I package that into the published gem file?
- Should I include the other auto-generated RBI files (in `./sorbet/rbi/sorbet-typed` and `./sorbet/rbi/hidden-definitions`) in the published gem file?
- Should I include the `typed` pragma comment in my gem's files, even though the type information is separated into an RBI file? If so, should it reflect the type information that's present in the file the comment is in, or should it reflect the type information available via the RBI file?

Comment: So you're asking for opinions?

Comment: @theTinMan the Sorbet team direct people to ask questions here, especially if things aren't clear from their documentation, and hence I'm doing so. I don't feel I'm asking for opinions, but rather: how should I do things to ensure they work with the Sorbet team's expectations and code.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding (I'm in a similar boat) based reading through [the custom RBI content](https://sorbet.org/docs/rbi#rbis-within-gems) is that they recommend writing the definitions in a `rbi` directory in the gem root directory. I don't think they should go in the the `sorbet` directory since that file gets quite large (and you don't want to have gem users having to download MBs of repeated definitions).

I've been putting the `typed` sigils in the library files that I have definitions for and having the RBI files separate. The `srb tc` picks up the definitions (and complains as appropriate). This means that I don't need to add sorbet as a gem dependency (other than for development).

Comment: I should note that this doesn't seem to add them into tests, which certainly makes this less helpful